# Arduino micro not recognized

Tags: arduino

Today I have an Arduino micro for some time and everything always worked well. Today, when I was uploading a code on this board using Arduino IDE, I accidentally started the Arduino Board update and the upload failed. After a while I retried again and again and again but upload always failed. Now my PC doesn't recognize my board and, looking in "device manager", when I connect my board, appears this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU2yS.jpg). What should I do? Have I to reflash bootloader? Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. The question is better suited for the [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Comment: Google up unbrick arduino micro

Comment: Thank you Michael, I'll look foto It. Stevieb, I have published It on Arduino Stack. I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have same thing but i figured out my cable was not original so i used samsung micro then windows saw my arduino on SERIAL PORT, COM5.Everythin is working correct now, all errors about cable go change the cable.